# Setting iis 8 on windows 8

Tags: .net, windows, iis, windows-8, iis-8

I am trying to setup IIS 8 on Windows 8.

[image]

This is the snap shot of Turn on/off window feature.

When i run the localhost in google chrome or any other browser it

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost
Did you mean: localhost.­net
Additional suggestions:
Go to localho.­st
Go to localhostr.­com
Try reloading: localhost
```

What i am missing.
IIS 8 is opening on inetmgr but i am not able to see the IIS 8 default page.

Comment: its not working with IE and chrome....

Comment: Check the bindings in IIS Manager and check, that the server and the site are running. - and sorry that i missed the "any other browser"

Comment: binding is fine and server is started still no results

Comment: Does it answer on http://127.0.0.1/ and does Ping localhost show this address?

Comment: yes its answering on 127.0.0.1

Comment: May be localhost resolves to ::1 (IPv6) and IIS does not answer on that?

Comment: what does this mean??/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31537/discussion-between-grumbler85-and-user1853803)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that IIS 8 (perhaps other versions, too) will refuse or not be able to bind to ::1 (which is localhost in IPv6-Terms). Since Win8 is IPv6-capable it will try to connect to IIS via IPv6, which then fails.

This can be circumvented by switching off IPv6 in the Properties of the Networking-Adapter in the System Management of Windows.